# copying a container that was passed by iterators

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, iterator

I have function that accepts container by begin and end :

```
template <class Titerator>  int foo(const Titerator& begin_data, const Titerator& end_data);
```

inside this function I want to do something like:

```
While there is reaming data{
  Do something on the remaining data
  delete some of the remaining data that satisfied a condition
}
```

Of course reaming data is a copy of the original data (original data will not be changed)

I can not think of a way to do it . I need to copy the data so I can do what ever I want on it but how to copy it while I do not know what the is the container? is it a vector, a list or what? I just have the begin and end. 
How can I define this function without loosing the generic concept ?

Comment: I'd recommend renaming the template parameter...

Comment: If you do not mind may you tell me: what do suggest and why ?

Comment: Here's the [reason](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tit?q=tit#tit-2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a copy of the data, you shouldn't care about what container it's originally in. That's the beauty of iterators: you don't have to care.

Choose the container for the copy based on the operations *you* want to do on that copy.

- Want frequent deletions in the middle? Consider `std::list`.
- Want cache-friendly, contiguous access? Consider `std::vector`.
- ... and so on.

Like this:

```
template <class Titerator>
int foo(const Titerator& begin_data, const Titerator& end_data)
{
  std::list<typename std::iterator_traits<Tierator>::value_type> myCopy{begin_data, end_data};
  // work on myCopy
}
```

Comment: Thanks..it seems logically. but in general, is there a way to copy it to the same container type ?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi No. There's no general way to go from "iterator" to "container." The iterator need not even correspond to a container at all - a raw pointer satisifes all the requirements of the Iterator concept, for example. Not to mention stuff like [Boost.Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html).